# glBindFrameBuffer not working with SDL

Tags: opengl, header, sdl, framebuffer

Recently I migrated over to SDL from Glut to get more control over the main loop. I've had shadow maps in my application for a while now using calls like bind framebuffer and gen  framebuffer. After migrating over to SDL, I get an error for undeclared Identifier for only these calls. I downloaded the SDL off the website today and imported SDL2/SDL.h and SDL2/SDL_opengl.h. When I open the declaration for one of these "missing calls" it gives it to me, in OpenGl/glext.h. I noticed that the SDL OpenGL imports the OpenGL/gl.h which imports glext.h. Is there a file I'm importing wrong? All the other OpenGl calls work in the rest of my program, so I have no idea what the problem is. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

EDIT: I was able to delve deeper into glut and was able to come up with this to get it to work:

```
#pragma comment (lib, "glu32.lib")
#include <OpenGL/glu.h>
```

Is this ok?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the platform you're using, but `glBindFramebuffer<ARB|EXT> (...)` is an extension on many. It was integrated into the core of OpenGL 3.0, so if your platform does not *guarantee* support for OpenGL 3.0 you are probably going to have to use an extension loading library (e.g. GLEW). If your driver provides OpenGL 3.0, you may still have to use the run-time extension mechanism to load the core function `glBindFramebuffer (...)`.

The fact that "glext.h" contains it does not say a whole lot. That header is where prototypes, enumerants / constants and typedefs for parts of OpenGL that are extended at run-time are defined. You still have to setup a function pointer in your software and ask the driver for the address before you can call them - this is what extension loading libraries do in a nutshell.

**EDIT1:**

No, that is not okay. `glBindFramebuffer (...)` is part of OpenGL 3.0. Microsoft Windows implements OpenGL 1.1, and GLU should not change this at all. If forcing MSVC to link against GLU fixes unresolved linker errors to an OpenGL 3.0 function something is seriously wrong.

**EDIT2:**

Judging by the discussion in the comments, you are not only moving from SDL to GLUT, but also from OS X to Win32. On Win32 you have to use `wglGetProcAddress (...)` or an extension loading library to use `glBindFramebuffer (...)`. You have been spoiled by Mac OS X, which is more of the exception than the rule when it comes to API completeness out-of-the-box.

Comment: Actually glBindFrameBuffer is not a extension. It's part of OpenGL core since version 3. Everything that does not carry a implementors designator (like EXT, ARB or such) *is not* an extension. However the extension mechanism is used to load later OpenGL versions functionality through the system supported ABI.

Comment: Thank you, that is what I meant to say :)

Comment: @datenwolf Then why would it work with Glut and not SDL? EDIT: I updated the question for something I was able to get to work, is it the proper method?

Comment: @BlueSpud: Well, actually no. GLU is so old and outdated, that I don't see any sane reason, why this would fix anything. You should not rely on such forms of "Voodoo" programming. I can only guess why it would work with your particular version of GLUT (I suppose you're not using the original, unmaintained legacy GLUT, but a modern incarnation of the library like FreeGLUT or OpenGLUT. If those happen to instantiate FBO functions for internal use those might leak to the outside. But I don't see how this could happen on Windows, without an explicit `__dllexport`; this is pure guesswork).

Comment: @datenwolf I'm on the mac, and using the default version of glut, so its the same across all the platforms. When I finish the application and put it on windows, then I'll worry about it then.

Comment: @BlueSpud If you're on a Mac, then those compiler directives are not going to do you any good. `#pragma comment (lib, ...)` is for Microsoft Visual C/C++. On OS X you can get `glBindFramebuffer (...)` merely by #including <GL/glext.h> and using the OpenGL framework. Nothing beyond that is necessary.

Comment: @BlueSpud: To complement Andon M. Coleman's comment: Not only you've been spoiled by MacOS X. You're also locked into any version of OS X and later you did develop the program for. The MacOS X OpenGL framework is not backward compatible. IMHO MacOS X is a horrible operating system to develop for (and to be honest also to work with).

Answer (score 1):

Everything that goes a certain version of OpenGL (Windows: 1.1, Linux 1.2) must be dynamically loaded through the so called *extension mechanism*. The OpenGL headers and including them are not enough. The typical recommendation is to use a [loading library like GLEW or glload](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/OpenGL_Loading_Library) to do the tedious work.